# Understanding the java soap stack - jaxb, jax-*, cfx, etc

Tags: java, xml, soap

Not having done any modern java in a while I am a bit overwhelmed by the plethora of acronyms around providing a soap service. Can you help me summarize what the following technologies are and how they relate to each other. Some of them are obvious but I am adding them to complete the picture:

- XML
- SOAP
- HTTP/TCP (think transports)
- XSD
- WSDL
- JAXB
- JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc.
- CFX

Let me know if I've missed something important from the list that I need to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XML** should be one of the obvious ones

**SOAP** is a protocol for creating remote procedure calls (web services)

**HTTP/TCP** transport protocols

**XSD** XML Schema Definition, defines the data types of your XML documents, useful for Schema validation and parsing to Java objects

**WSDL** web service definition language, a descriptor for SOAP based web services. Contains the operations you can call and the data (using XSD) to use. The WSDL puts it all together.

**JAXB** API for binding XML and Java types, so you can parse XML files to Java objects and vice versa

**JAX-WS** API for SOAP based web services

**JAX-RS** API for RESTful web services (alternative to SOAP)

[**CFX**](http://cxf.apache.org/) is a framework from Apache for web services. All other technologies above are just APIs / standards, CFX is an implementation of these.

Comment: +1 - It is worth noting that JAXB is the default binding layer for both JAX-WS and JAX-RS.  JAXB is also used by JAX-WS implementations to produce the schema portion of WSDLs.  Also JAXB models can be generated for XSDs.

Answer (score 0):

- XML

  markup language favoured by SOAP webservices. You should be considering whether JSON meets your needs
- SOAP

  Used to mean Simplified Object Appliction Protocol, but really now means 'non-RESTful' web services
- HTTP/TCP (think transports)

  Webservices tend to use HTTP, but don't have to. Benefit of HTTP is ubiquity / firewall punching (via proxies)
- XSD

  XML schema Definition - a 'better' validation framework for XML than DOCTYPE. This is arguable. XSD is overly heavyweight for many applications
- WSDL

  Web Service Description Language - defines the methods/parameters of SOAP based webservices. Arguably too heavyweight for many applications
- JAXB

  Java XML Binding - allows XML <-> Java object <-> XML roundtripping. Can be difficult to work with for non-trivial examples
- JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc.

  JAX-WS is the (large) family of webservice standards around SOAP

  JAX-RS is the API for RESTful webservices.
- CFX

  ???
- REST

  An alternative to SOAP webservices based on Roy Fieldings [paper](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). Often considered simpler than SOAP and easier to use. But care is needed to implement correctly, Noteably HATEOAS (Hypertext As The Engine Of Application State) is often misunderstood.
- JSON

  Javascript Object Notation - an alternative data representation to XML based on Javascript data literals